# Is There an API Manual Available for DOORS DXL RCR Functions?

Tags: ibm-doors

I've tried locating a manual describing what can be done with RCRs within DOORS via DXL. Examining DXL here and there in the installation files, I can find some references to RCR functions, but I can't find a definitive manual. Is there a resource listing DXL RCR functions available for DOORS?

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think that most of the features of RCR and IR have been programmed into the GUI and AFAIK there is no official API for the communication between a Change Tool and DOORS apart from the standard OSLC documentation

Answer (score 0):

No official API documentation exists.

RCR DXL functions, however, do exist, though, like for example:

`bool cmHasReviewFlagFile(Module m)` determines if the module is in RCR review mode.